# Checking possible Hazards from Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mars-simulator

I'm trying to understand data hazards and have a question with the following code.  To my understanding, data hazards are back to back instructions that call the same addresses, however, I'm trying to figure out if it differs when using branching instructions.  For example:

in the scenario

```
add $s0, $0, $s0
add $s1, $s0, $a1
```

the repeated $s0 could cause a data hazard.  However, does this change when using branching assembly instructions?

```
add $s0, $0, $s0
beq $t0, $t1, A5
or $s0, $s0, $0
```

Does the above code result in a data hazard from instruction 1 to instruction 3 because of the repeated $0 and $s0 or no?

Answer (score 1):

`$0` discards writes; the zero register can't be part of a data hazard<sup>1</sup>.  Also it's not written in any of your instructions.

Note 1: An implementation that does bypass-forwarding needs to special case `$0` and *not* forward in that case.  But a simplistic implementation that stalls on RAW hazards could work by detecting any match between a just-written and a source operand for a later instruction, and stall until the reg write makes it into the register file.  This would be safe (not forwarding possibly-non-zero data - the register file will always read `$0` as 0), merely sub-optimal but keeping the register-matching hardware even more simple.

---

On a variant of MIPS without branch-delay slots, the `beq` could matter; you have to follow the dynamic path of execution because that's the order in which instructions go through the pipeline.

On a real MIPS with a branch-delay slot after every branch, the `or $s0, $s0, $0` NOP *always* executes whether `beq` is taken or not.  `$s0` is an input to that instruction, and was written 2 instructions ago (along the dynamic path of execution) by another NOP, `add $s0, $0, $s0`.  So yes, that's [a RAW hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards) that would need bypass forwarding or stalling<sup>2</sup>, if we're talking about a classic 5-stage pipeline.  A short-enough pipeline would mean no hazard.

Also a potential WAW and WAR hazard, but since there's a WAR hazard the later instruction can't run until the earlier instruction produces a result.

And of course that applies if the branch is not taken, even on a MIPS-like pipeline *without* branch-delay slots because the `or` runs 2 instructions after the `add`.

Footnote 2:
Or special-casing `add` and `or` with the zero register (and writing back to one of the sources) as true NOPs not having input dependencies...  But note that real MIPS can't do that because it would violate memory dependency ordering (C++ `memory_order_consume`) ISA rules.